# How do you import one C++20 module into another C++ Module when using clang++?

Tags: c++, c++20, clang++, c++-modules

I have the following two modules:

module_a.cppm:

```cpp
export module module_a;

export namespace A_Namespace{
  const int A_Export = 2;
}
```

module_b.cppm:

```cpp
export module module_b;

import module_a;

export namespace B_Namespace
{
    const int B_Export = A_Namespace::A_Export + 1;
}
```

I want to compile these modules into `.pcm` files for use in an executable. To do so, I use the following commands:

```bash
clang++ -fmodules-ts --precompile module_a.cppm -o module_a.pcm
clang++ -fmodules-ts --precompile module_b.cppm -o module_b.pcm
```

And then `module_a.pcm` and `module_b.pcm` would get compiled into `.o` files, which are then compiled into my final executable.

The `module_a.pcm` file compiles successfully, however `module_b.pcm` outputs the following error:

```bash
fatal error: module 'module_a' not found
```

I suspect that this is because the definition for module_a is not provided when compiling module_b. Were I using the traditional `.hpp`/`.cpp` combination, I would compile the sources for `module_a.cpp` and `module_b.cpp` into a single binary, and the header files `module_a.hpp` and `module_b.hpp` would provide a declaration that the compiler can satisfy.

How do you satisfy module-interdependencies during compilation?

The above was produced using clang++ 14.0.0 on an x64 Ubuntu 22.04 instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules can not import other modules, only system libraries (e.g `import <iostream>;`).

This functionality is supported by C++ as module partitions.

I've included a partition example:

`module_a.cppm`:

```
export module MyModule;

export namespace A_Namespace{
  const int A_Export = 2;
}
```

`module_b.cppm`:

```
export module MyModule:b;

export namespace B_Namespace
{
    const int B_Export = A_Namespace::A_Export + 1;
}
```

However clang v14 does not yet support the syntax:

> module_b.cppm:1:23: error: sorry, module partitions are not yet supported

It is documented as [supported in Clang v15](https://releases.llvm.org/15.0.0/tools/clang/docs/StandardCPlusPlusModules.html).

Comment: I guess I misunderstood modules! Thank you. I had expected that they were intended to replace #include altogether, but I guess not